# Maximal subset iff maximum size

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Let $X$ be a finite set with at least one element and $\eta\subseteq 2^X$ a collection of subsets of $X$ such that
$$A\cup B\in\eta\text{ for every }A,B\in\eta$$
$$X=\bigcup_{A\in\eta}A$$
$$\text{For every }x,y\in X\text{ there exists }A\in\eta\text{ which contains one of them but not the other}$$
Now, for every $x\in X$ let
$$\eta_x=\{\,A\in\eta\;:\;x\in A\,\}$$
The $\eta_x$ can be ordered either by size or by set inclusion. Is it true that $\eta_x$ is maximal (not a subset of any other $\eta_y$) if and only if $|\eta_x|=\max_{z\in X}|\eta_z|$ ?

Of course, if $|\eta_x|$ is the maximum then $\eta_x$ is maximal, but I'm having trouble proving the converse. All I know is that 1) If $A\in\eta$ has maximum size then $|A|=|X|-1$ and 2) Every $\eta_x$ contains one such set of maximum size.

For an attempt at a proof, if $|\eta_x|$ is not the maximum then 1) There exists $y\in X$ with $|\eta_x|<|\eta_y|$ and 2) One can choose an $A\in\eta_x$ of maximum size and take the only element $z\in X\setminus A$. The proof must continue trough one of these two because there aren't any other "interesting" points that we can focus on, but I can't finish the proof.

Thanks!

Comment: Is $X$ supposed to be finite?  Your "of course" is not at all obvious in the infinite case.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes, $X$ is finite

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a simple counterexample, let $X=\{a,b,c\}$ and let $\eta$ be the collection of subsets $A\subseteq X$ such that if $c\in A$ then $b\in A$.  Then $\eta_a$ and $\eta_b$ are both maximal, with $$\eta_a=\{\{a\},\{a,b\},\{a,b,c\}\}$$ having 3 elements and $$\eta_b=\{\{b\},\{a,b\},\{b,c\},\{a,b,c\}\}$$ having 4 elements.

Comment: Thanks! No wonder why the proof seemed elusive.

Comment: Do you know if a similar proposition could be true? Maybe the $|\eta_x|$ for maximal $\eta_x$ is at least the $\max -1$ ?

Comment: No, nothing of that sort should be true.  Given any partial order on $X$, you could let $\eta$ consist of the upward closed sets in the partial order, and then the maximal $\eta_x$'s are just the ones that correspond to maximal $x$ in the partial order.  Playing with a variety of simple partial orders should give you a sense of the range of possiblities.  (My example is the partial order where $c\leq b$ and otherwise everything is incomparable.)

Comment: @augustoperez Let $|X|=n$ and $a\in X$. Define $$\eta=\{A\subseteq X:|A|\ge n-1\text{ or }a\notin A\}.$$ Then $\eta_x$ is maximal for each $x\in X$, but $|\eta_a|=n$ while $|\eta_x|=2^{n-2}+n-1$ for $x\in X\setminus\{a\}$.